# Delete Product Images For Products That Are Disabled

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, product-images, delete

Is there a way to delete all images for products that are set as disabled?

It's just a lot of my products that are disabled are taking my storage space up on my server.

I'd just like to be able to cron a PHP script every week or so however I'm unsure what this script might actually look like?

Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

//This method will work if you hit the file on root. There can be many rectifications for this. But please make sure to take proper backup before running this
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors",'On');

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('status',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);

$products->load();
foreach($products as $product) {

$id = $product->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$mediaGalleryAttribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->loadByCode($entityTypeId, 'media_gallery');
$gallery = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
foreach ($gallery as $image)
    $mediaGalleryAttribute->getBackend()->removeImage($product, $image->getFile());
$product->save();

}
```